# PHP Infinite loop, best way to set and stop in windows

Tags: php, windows, infinite-loop

I have a php file that is designed to check data from a remote API (which I don't control) to see if there is any updated data.

What is the best way to set an infinite loop on this file so that it's always running?

What is the best way to stop it?

Basically, my code says

```
<?php
...check for updated data from API
       ....do stuff...

...if there is nothing to do...then keep on looping until there is something to do
?>
```

This is all on Windows.

Thank you.

Comment: could you paste your code here so we can understand clearly?

Comment: I have code, but I don't think its relevant. Basically, I want the contents of this file to run forever

Comment: `while (True) { if (foo()) { do_stuff(); } else { sleep(1); } }` ... Or something ... Really, post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CRON job.

If you try to have an infinite looping script and are on shared hosting, expect your account to be suspended fairly quickly.

Comment: I'm on Windows, so I guess I could use Windows task scheduler to run every minute or so.  That might be the best solution.